# WildFly -> Undertow -> mapping subdomain to war file not working

Tags: apache, jboss, subdomain, wildfly, undertow

WildFly 8.1.0 Final
    Windows Server 2012 R2

I have two sub-domains pointing at this server, and I want requests to each sub-domain to trigger a different war file:-

```
webapp.domain1.com -> WildFly Server -> myapp1.war
test.domain2.net -> WildFly Server -> myapp2.war
```

My standalone.xml file is currently configured as follows based on advice received on the JBoss Developer site:-

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
  <buffer-cache name="default"/>

  <server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>

    <host name="default-host" default-web-module="myapp1.war" alias="webapp.domain1.com"/>
    <host name="other-host" default-web-module="myapp2.war" alias="test.domain2.net"/>
  </server>

  <servlet-container name="default">
    <jsp-config/>
  </servlet-container>

  <filters>
    <response-header name="server-header" header-value="WildFly/8" header-name="Server"/>
    <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-value="Undertow/1" header-name="X-Powered-By"/>
  </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Pointing a browser at webapp.domain1.com or test.domain2.net results in the request being sent to the WildFly server as expected, but the same war file (myapp1.war) is triggered in both cases.

Switching the 'name' values of the <host .../> elements as follows results in myapp2.war being called whichever URL is used:-

```
    <host name="other-host" default-web-module="myapp1.war" alias="webapp.domain1.com"/>
    <host name="default-host" default-web-module="myapp2.war" alias="test.domain2.net"/>
```

It looks like Undertow is only processing details of the "default-host" entry.

Can anyone here help with this please?

Failing that, does anyone know if (and how) WildFly can be used with Apache Web Server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in current undertow subsystem implementation. 
It only properly processes default-web-module for default host and doesn't even take it into account for non default hosts.

I created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3639 to track & fix it.

as a workaround until this is fixed add

`jboss-web.xml` to `WEB-INF` of your myapp2.war

with content:

```
<jboss-web>
    <virtual-host>other-host</virtual-host>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

which will tell server to what host & context root it should be bound to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - and sorry for the delay in replying.  This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a setup similar to yours on Ubuntu 14.04 with WildFly 8.1.0.Final and Firefox 30, and for me, it works after adding a `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` to one my wars:

```
<jboss-web>
    <virtual-host>other-host</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

I defined two different host aliases for the same IP in my /etc/hosts, and my browser gets redirected to the different web apps for `http://alias1:8080` and `http://alias2:8080` as expected.

Answer (score -2):

default-host is the virtual host that will be used if an incoming request as no Host: header. So to get the requests to your other server, the request sent by the client should have "Host: other-host" in the request header.

A sample HTTP request from client looks like,

```
GET /Some/Resource HTTP/1.1
Accept: ....
Host: other-host
....
....
```

See if this works.